# Difference between DB2 Version

Tags: sql, db2

What are the noticable differences between DB2 version 9.7 and DB2 version 10? is it worth upgrading to Version 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say on which operating system (Windows, Linux, z/OS) you want to run DB2 10.

Here's an [IBM online sales brochure](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2-warehouse-10/) that lists the new DB2 10 features.

My advice is to hold off on any upgrades to any mission critical software unless you're applying a bug fix you need, or the software is about to go off maintenance.  Let other users and shops find the problems.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the OS, it's windows. Thanks for the link

Comment: IBM's recent release of the first Fix Pack for DB2 10.1 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows platforms is an encouraging development, even for shops running DB2 9.7. Many shops have a fairly strict rule about not running something in production until the vendor releases one or two sets of support patches, so you may not want to upgrade straight away, but it's definitely a good time to start testing your migration. The V10.1 release offers some new features such as bitemporal data tables, which require changes to your existing applications, so it's best to allow yourself some time to investigate.